High temperature in seal oil vacuum pump (not in the bearing), steam power plant. Why the seal oil vacuum pump suddenly increased in temperature?
Seal oil vacuum pump in steam power plant, suddenly have temperature increased, it's in the pump's body, not in the bearing. Why is that happen?
I noticed that temperature of main seal oil tank in this unit is higher than in another unit, thus, in my opinion, the temperature increased in seal oil vacuum pump body due to high temperature in main seal oil tank. But, I believe that's not a root cause, there must be something in generator system, especially the seal ring and hydrogen cooling system.
Do anyone ever have the same problem? Would you please tell me why and how to overcome this problem?

more gas leaking out of the seals this pump services?

No leakage on the pump was observed, including inlet and outlet gasket. The pump was maintained by replacing the bearings and other parts (including cleaning it), but the problem still arise. The cleaning of seal oil separator was already performed too.
